# NewsActivity cannot be converted to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

На вызов **MainActivity**:

```
.withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
   @Override public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
       if (drawerItem != null) {
           Intent intent = null;
           if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 0) {
               getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new Fragment1()).commit();
           } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 1) {
                      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new NewsActivity()).commit();
                  } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 100)
```

Тут пишет ошибку:

> Error:(111, 110) error: incompatible types: NewsActivity cannot be converted to Fragment

Фрагмент **NewsActivity**:

```
public class NewsActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String RANK = "rank";
    static String COUNTRY = "country";
    static String POPULATION = "population";
    static String FLAG = "flag";
    // URL Address
    String url = "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsouplistview.html";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
       new JsoupListView().execute();
    }

    // Title AsyncTask
    private class JsoupListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android Jsoup ListView Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            try {
                // Connect to the Website URL
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                // Identify Table Class "worldpopulation"
                for (Element table : doc.select("table[class=worldpopulation]")) {
                    // Identify all the table row's(tr)
                    for (Element row : table.select("tr:gt(0)")) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // Identify all the table cell's(td)
                        Elements tds = row.select("td");

                        // Identify all img src's
                        Elements imgSrc = row.select("img[src]");
                        // Get only src from img src
                        String imgSrcStr = imgSrc.attr("src");

                        // Retrive Jsoup Elements
                        // Get the first td
                        map.put("rank", tds.get(0).text());
                        // Get the second td
                        map.put("country", tds.get(1).text());
                        // Get the third td
                        map.put("population", tds.get(2).text());
                        // Get the image src links
                        map.put("flag", imgSrcStr);
                        // Set all extracted Jsoup Elements into the array
                        arraylist.add(map);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
       }
    }
}
```

Подчеркнуто красным:

`.replace(R.id.frame_container, new NewsActivity()).commit();`

и пишет:

> Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: , required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace` требует фрагмент вы же ему пытаетесь активити передать. Именно об этомм вам дословно сообщает компилятор